# google sheet countif and filter out other columns if the value is lotto

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column

```
COLUMN H | Column R

trading type | Closed P&L
Lotto | 100%
Lotto | 200%
      | 100%
Day   | -50%
```

Trying to exclude any rows that have trading type = Lotto and calculate the "non-lotto" winning rate. Curious how could I do so?

So in this case the total non-lotto trades are 2, and only 1 win (>0%) => 50% winning rate.

This doesn't seem to do the jobs

```
=countif(R2:R148,">0")/COUNT(R2:R165, H:H, "Lotto")
```

This will return N/A

```
=countif(R2:R148,">0", H:H, "Lotto")/COUNT(R2:R165, H:H, "Lotto")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en) to get the non `Lotto` cases where the value is positive and divide it with the total number of non `Lotto` cases:

```
=COUNTIFS(H2:H5,"<>Lotto",R2:R5,">0")/COUNTIF(H2:H5,"<>Lotto")
```

[image]

Comment: You are correct Marios. I totally misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! @marikamitsos initially I misunderstood it too until I read it carefully.